# Connect & interact with dApp without wallet connection

Tags: web3js, metamask, dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp, security

I have a question regarding the issues I am facing on my current project. I am building NFT marketplace on the Polygon network.
The specific requirement is we should allow the users can interact with the smart contracts without metamask installed on the browser.
I found the solution so the users can just input their wallet address to login our dapp and can interact with the smart contracts through the special `Operator` smart contract which will pay for the gas fees instead of the user.

But we're facing the huge security issue here. The user can input any wallet address, even the other's, so he can manage the NFTs which are not be owned by him.
This is caused because we don't have any verification system to identify the user is the real owner of the wallet.

We don't like to let the users input any personal information like Email address.
The possible solutions we're thinking about is using password when they input the wallet address so that we can verify the user's real owner.
In this case, we will need to track the user's wallet address and password using separate database.

We're still not sure this is the best solution, so if you have any good idea, we will really happy to hear from you.

Here you can check the current progress here.
https://deploy-preview-26--dev-offero.netlify.app/